# Android Navigation - Hide action bar for loading/splash screen?

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph, android-navigation-bar, android-components

I am wondering if there is a good pattern/method for hiding the action bar for splash/loading screens??  I understand the pattern isn't great, but we are retrofitting an existing app that uses patterns like this.
Regardless, this would seem like a common thing to want to do for things like dialogs or  fullscreen fragments where you might not necessarily want the Action Bar displayed.

I know it can be done fairly simply with something like

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        activity?.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)?.visibility = GONE
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        activity?.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)?.visibility = VISIBLE
    }
```

But I was just curious if there is a better way to control the Action bar with NavOptions or something similar.

Comment: I had a similar problem, your approach is what I used, just you can simply use activity?.supportActionBar?.hide() if you have not added the toolbar manually inside your activity.

Answer (score 2):

Set the style of the splash screen activity to

`Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar`

Or some similar `NoActionBar` style

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **`addOnDestinationChangedListener`**.
Something like:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.splash_screen) {
       toolbar.visibility = View.GONE
   } else {
       toolbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
}
```

**As alternative** you can use something different. Don't use a `Fragment` for the loading screen.
Define an app theme only for the loading screen:

```
<style name="LoadingTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/loading_background</item>
</style>
```

In the `Manifest` apply this theme to your `MainActivity`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:theme="@style/LoadingTheme">
```

Finally in your `MainActivity`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_NoActionBar)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    //.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

or you can change it directly in Manifest

```
<activity 
    android:name=".AnActivity"
    android:label="@string/a_string"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1) Inside fragment use,**

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
}
```

**2. In Activity use,**

`getSupportActionBar().hide();`

OR by creating a new style in **styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

and use the style at the activity of **manifest.xml**

```
<activity ...
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" > ...
</activity>
```